# Unity3d embedded compiler or interpreter

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is this possible to embed some compiler inside a scene using unity 3d ? Is there any class to communicate ? I would like to pick some compiler already done and use it inside an educational game .

Lets suppose i like to develop a game with c# or js and i need to use a c compiler without developing a compiler from scratch. Or even an interpreter like python.

For windows we got some simulator like cygwin to run linux commands inside, even using virtual machine. I thought i can use a compiler or interpreter without a VM.

ty in advance

I know this is possible on minecraft when u install forge and computercraft. It simulates a computer inside a minecraft and it has craftOS, lua programs, and an IDE.

Comment: It depends on the language you want to do.

Comment: Have you checked Lua plugins from asset store?

Comment: @JoeBlow I did not vote it down, but I would say because "the question does not show any research effort" like the downvote button says. Like mgear said after you, did he check the asset store yet? If so why did not one of the existing available options work? Also, because the OP is just asking for "Some compiler" and never specifies which language, that makes this question overly broad.

Comment: Scott - yeah, fair one

Comment: Oki ... ty for the backup. Actually i have this question inside unity3d community and got no aswer whatsoever yet. If u have seen something inside the asset store, please, tell me whitch one or at least the name of the asset. I am looking for this answer for long time. TY and i am sorry. Really. I saw LUA plugin in the AS. This is not the case. I would like to teach those languages inside the game, no programm the game with it. Is it clear ?